# PHP arithmetic operation where number starts with zero

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
$a = 012;
echo $a/4;
echo '<br>';
echo $a+4;
echo '<br>';
echo $a;
```

This generates the following output:

```
2.5
14
10
```

However, I expect:

```
3
16
12
```

Why does this happen when `$a` starts with a 0?

Comment: You have an octal number.

Comment: echo $a, and you will see. How you get this number?

Comment: @ Rizier123 Can you please give me any reference where i can understand the reason of the output ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already specified by [@Rizier123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3933332/rizier123) you must follow the integer type doc.

As specified in the official documentation of integers type http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

> Integers can be specified in decimal (base 10), hexadecimal (base 16), octal (base 8) or binary (base 2) notation, optionally preceded by a sign (- or +)

```
$n = 123; // decimal number
$n = -123; // negative number
$n = 0234; // octal number
...
```

So in your case the first number `$a = 012` means that it's in octal notation.

When you do the division: `$a/4` PHP proceed with [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) converting it to decimal base and dividing by 4

```
$a = 012; // 10 in decimal base
echo $a/4; // 10/4 -> 2.5
```

**Note:** *Prior to PHP 7, if an invalid digit was given in an octal integer (i.e. 8 or 9), the rest of the number was ignored*

Answer (score 1):

The answer is down to the 0 in front defining the number as an octal (instead of a normal base 10 number). Note the page on [Integers in the PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php):

```
<?php
$a = 1234; // decimal number
$a = -123; // a negative number
$a = 0123; // octal number (equivalent to 83 decimal)
$a = 0x1A; // hexadecimal number (equivalent to 26 decimal)
$a = 0b11111111; // binary number (equivalent to 255 decimal)
?>
```

So basically an octal is where numbers go up to 7 in each column instead of 9. Therefore the 1 in the rightmost column makes the number an 8, the two in the leftmost column adds 2 on, therefore the number is 10.

In hexadecimal numbers defined in PHP by starting with `0x` they count to 15 (known as base 15); A representing 10, B representing 11,.. all the way up to F representing 15. Binary numbers (in PHP they are defined by starting with `0b`) on the other hand only go up to 1, they only have two values in each column 0 and 1.

You can use the `octdec` function to get around this (converting the octal to a decimal):

```
<?php
$a = octdec(012);
echo $a/4;
echo '<br>';
echo $a+4;
echo '<br>';
echo $a;
?>
```

When the division happens, PHP does some [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) and the octal is converted to an integer. Hence why you get the result you do.

Before PHP 7 invalid numbers in octals (like 8 or 9) were ignored, [in PHP 7 they now cause an error](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/987).

Answer (score 0):

For good answer please open [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/understanding-octal-numbers-in-php/63278).

`012` is octal number. In octal, numbers consist of 8 decimals. Start number with zero. skip remaining 2 digit left 12.

```
8^0 = 1,8^1=8 So 8+2=10 

10/4 = 2.5 => $a+4 = 10 + 4 = 14;
```